# Stringtemplate 4 (st4) - Render if string is not empty

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I need an st4 expression to render an element if a string is not empty:

`<if(theString)>...<endif>` does not work - it seems to only work for arrays.

I've tried `if(theString.length > 0)` and all kinds of stuff, but it looks like it this only works for variables that are not set or for arrays.

I am iterating over a list and rendering this, so I could have values in the middle that are empty strings that I don't want to render anything at all for.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling trying to find the ability to compare strings in a conditional. I want to be able to test for a condition like `obj.Name == 'foobar'`.  Not sure if stringtemplate-4 can do it?

To render if the value is not null you should be able to do the following.

```
$if(obj.Name)$ $obj.Name$ $endif$    // prints the Name property of obj
```

But to find the length of a string you can use `strlen` function.

ie.

```
// obj.Name = "foobar", prints 'Length of Name is 6'
$if(strlen(obj.Name))$ Length of Name is $strlen(obj.Name)$ $endif$
```

Here is a helpful list of all the [functions](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet.md):
https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet.md

Comment: You'll see I have an array, not a String

Comment: then use length([array var]).  Something i found out working through this is that all you can evaluate is TRUE|FALSE.  There is no if (x > 3).  X is false if its null or 0, and true if its 1 or more.  The best answer I read was that StringTemplte4 is the View within the MVC framework.  And (x > 3) amounts to controller logic.